# python sqlite: finding the average of part of a column after sorting. (possibly pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a table (x), in a database (test.db) , which has three columns (name, rate, recorded_at).

There are around 500 rows in this table and i am trying to get the average of the last 30 entries that were added. I know I can get the average of all the entries by using pandas but i am struggling to figure out how to sort the data and THEN get an average from the results.

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT rate FROM x ORDER BY recorded_at DESC")
result1 = c.fetchmany(30)
    for many in result1:
        x = sum(many)
        print(x)
```

this is one of the ways i have tried but it isn't going to work as it isn't going to collect the data from the loop.

I have tried with pandas but again i can get the average of all the values of the column but not of just the ordered results or of the last 30.

Can anyone please suggest a way that I can get this to work? If you have a better suggestion can you please point me in the right direction? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Mort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do the computation directly in the database?

```
select avg(rage) avg_rate
from (select rate from x order by recorded_at desc limit 30) t
```

This is obviously more efficient than fetching all rows of the table, then doing the computation on client side.

Comment: I will try and implement this method! BRB....thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: got it!     c.execute("SELECT avg(rate) avg_rate from (select rate from x order by recorded_at desc limit 30)")

Comment: took me a while to figure out how to put that in python (I am new to programming in general) but thank you very much for showing me the way!